# VScode C++ debug for const type& expressions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am doing some debugging in a CFD code (several lines of code).

Due the size of the structures it is common to see something like this:

```
const vectorField& a = grid.CellCenters();
```

This is all good, but in some parts of the code the `const type&` will not point to any predefined structure and its value will change. (I assume it is pointing to some random location in memory).

I would like to catch this type of errors in VSCode. I can do it manually by setting a watcher on the variable:

e.g., `a[0]` will give me the coordinates of the first vector in `a`and I can visually check if the value changes as the code moves forward.

This, however is very cumbersome as several variables can exist with this behavior.

I would like to know if there is a way to a breakpoint on the data of a structure, e.g., a vector. If its value changes, the solver will stop.

Comment: "but in some parts of the code the const type& will not point to any predefined structure and its value will change. (I assume it is pointing to some random location in memory)." it is not clear what you mean by that. An object to which you hold a constant reference is not necessarily `const`, you cannot modify it via the `const` reference, but it can be modified through other means, and that is not an error

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! 
At the current time, I do not know enough to give you specifics. I just know that If put the variable in the watch the values keep changing, and I would like the debugger to stop whenever this happens.

Comment: You can stop the debugger when a variable change but it only works for one 32 bits (or less) variable at a time. Thus, if you want to check many fields in a structure, it might not be a good way. Usually, it should be easier to put breakpoints on each setter. Data breakpoints are usually useful in event driven application when you know that a variable is modified but you cannot easily find where using other technics (maybe you have a lot of object but you want to detect a change in a specific one). You might also consider conditionnal breakpoints or making small changes for debugging purpose.